# Java - Response JSON to Object

Tags: java

I tried to create a generic method to read the response json but I don't like to have a generic object with many hashmaps... I don't want to specify the type. I want to get the content for Country, City, etc...

[image: This is my result]

```
AwsProxyResponse response = get("/countries");
List<Country> countryList = (List<Country>) jsonStringToObject(response.getBody()).get("countries"); // doesn't work
```

```
protected Object jsonStringToObject(String jsonString) throws IOException {
JsonObject jsonData = new JsonObject(jsonString);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.readValue(jsonData.toString().getBytes(), Object.class);
}
```

What is the proper way to get the Response data and then fetch what I need (e.g. content, totalElements, etc...)

Comment: If you don't specify the type everything will resolved to map, because `Map<String, Object>` is the closest structure in java to represent json. If you don't want to work with a map, you need to create your custom class whose structure will match response json. Or write your custom deserializer, which will extract only what you need.

Comment: @Chaosfire isn't there already an object like this in Spring? Something like ResponseBody, I don't know...

Comment: Spring does have a page class, with similar structure to the picture you posted, but it is not used for deserialization, and it can be tricky. Btw [why you should not post pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Also, how is spring supposed to know every possible response from every possible server, and have a class prepared for it(that would be the page content in **your** case)? The options are literally infinite... I think you should start with the very basics of json deserialization... This [object mapper intro](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) and [custom deserialization guide](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) are a good start.